# ksoap2 Android unexpected type in response

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Im trying to make a call to a java web service using ksoap2. I am using the ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar and Android API level 8.

Activity Code:

```
private static final String SECURITY_NAMESPACE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
private static final String USERNAME_TOKEN_NAMESPACE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
private static final String PASSWORD_TYPE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    Element usernameElement = new Element().createElement(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "Username");
    usernameElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "username");
    Element passwordElement = new Element().createElement(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "Password");
    passwordElement.setAttribute(null, "Type", PASSWORD_TYPE);
    passwordElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, "password");

    Element usernameTokenElement = new Element().createElement(USERNAME_TOKEN_NAMESPACE, "UsernameToken");
    usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernameElement);
    usernameTokenElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, passwordElement);

    Element securityElement = new Element().createElement(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "Security");
    securityElement.setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand", "1");
    securityElement.setPrefix(null, SECURITY_NAMESPACE);
    securityElement.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernameTokenElement);

    Element[] header = new Element[]{securityElement};

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.headerOut = header;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    try{
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Soap", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

When i make the call i get the following exception:

```
06-12 13:01:51.563: E/Soap(471): unexpected type (position:TEXT ������������U��n� ...@3:97 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f5de78) 

06-12 13:01:51.563: E/Soap(471): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT ������������U��n� ...@3:97 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44f5de78)
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Could it be something to do with character encoding, GZIP or incorrect soap version?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: Try to switch to `SoapEnvelope.VER12` (instead of VER11).

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when i'm using ksoap2 2.6.5. I fixed that with ver. 2.5.4

Here :  http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/#ksoap2-android-assembly%2F2.5.4